# Google app engine does not seem to reload java class files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I uploaded a version of my app to the GAE with changed java classes and jars. However, According to the behavior of the app, I do not believe GAE reloaded the java classes or libs. For example, I expected it should write a line to the log in the new version but I didn't see it in the log from the app admin console.  I tried following methods, but none of them worked:

- shutdown the instance from the app admin console for that version and let it start a new instance by accessing the url
- delete the version and re-upload the same version again
- upload the app using a new (different) version name
- set the version as the default version
- make the version not the default version

This issue real really drives me crazy. Has anyone had the similar problem before? Am I missing anything with the app?

I found [this link discussed a similar issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/YOpsFvHw2rk), but without an answer. I even tried disable/enable app mentioned in that post, but still no luck.

Comment: Is the version is set to default version?

Comment: I tried both: set the version as default version and not default version. But none of them worked.

Comment: It's easy to make a mistake with logging like logging at a level that will not show up, or logging inside a conditional branch that does not get hit, even though it looks like it will get hit to you. Make a change that is really impossible to ignore, like replacing your main page with "Hello world".

Comment: @RobinGreen Thank you for your comments. All the static files are updated. The only thing is the updated java classes were not loaded. I then tried to rename the java class e.g., the name of context listener, and that class finally got reloaded (actually it is loaded as it's a new class) and the log shown up in the admin console. However, there are still some classes not reloaded...